# Heavy CPU Usage by scrapy crawler

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, web-crawler, cpu-usage, scrapyd

I've multiple spiders running in multiple instances (4) parallelly. All of them are using almost 100% cpu usage.

I've deployed them using scrapyd. Tried changing scrapyd settings like max_concurrent_requests,CONCURRENT_REQUESTS,CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN to minimum but no luck.

I'm using python 2.7.5 and
scrapy 0.24

I've googled for solution and found this page

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scrapy-users/Rgq07ldcoPs

I couldn't get their solutions

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed this. Issue was with frequent Mysql updation, eventually leading to a load on CPU. Introduced a minute delay in pipeline to reduce the load, which fixed the whole issue.

Comment: thanks for the hint!, looks like I am doing the same mistake. I'll try setting some kind of batch insert

Comment: Did you check CPU usage per process before solving this issue? I think if MySQL is the problem, process viewers (htop, top, glances, whatever) will point out MySQL process, not the python. If you measured it, please share what you saw!